# uncommon function of classes used in one template function in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I will pass "stack" and "queue" as template type in following codes.

Knowing that .front() and .top() is not the common function between "queue" and "stack", I use "if" to check.

But it still couldn't compile. (error C2039: 'top' is not the member of std::queue<_Ty>)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
template<typename T>
void push_pop(string *str, T *containers){
    string s = typeid(containers).name();
    if(s[11]=='q'){
        str->push_back(containers->front()); containers->pop();
    }else{
        str->push_back(containers->top()); containers->pop();
    }
}
```

I know I could use function overloading but I want to solve this using template.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: still you will need separate functions to execute either `containers->front()` or `containers->top()`

Comment: A check based on the result of `typeid(containers).name()` is probably a not so good idea. Better use template specialization to handle this situaltion.

Comment: Yes, use an SFINAE test to see if the passed in class supports `front()` or `top()` and then handle accordingly.. (search this site for SFINAE, there are lots of ways of doing it...)

Comment: Is there anything from stopping you to just provide two specializations for this?

Comment: @Mario : No, I am just curious that if there is a way to achieve what I think within one function body.

Answer (score 1):

(untested) - I use a macro like the following:

```
#define FUNC_TEST(func)                                                     \
template<typename T>                                                        \
struct has_##func                                                           \
{                                                                           \
  template <typename _1> static std::true_type  test(decltype(&_1::func)*); \
  template <typename   > static std::false_type test(...);                  \
  static const bool value =  decltype(test<T>(0))::value;                   \
}
```

Then, for all the functions I need to test for, I would use the macro to generate the test code, for example:

```
FUNC_TEST(top);
FUNC_TEST(front);
```

Then, I would define several helper functions to handle the actual push back:

```
// If the type supports top(), then the first variant is enabled and selected
template <typename F>
inline enable_fn<has_top<F>, void> use_top(F* o, std::string* dest)
{ dest->push_back(o->top()); }
template <typename F>
inline disable_fn<has_top<F>, void> use_top(F*, std::string*)
{ }

// If the type supports front(), the first variant is selected from below automatically
template <typename F>
inline enable_fn<has_front<F>> use_front(F* o, std::string* dest)
{ dest->push_back(o->front()); }
template <typename F>
inline disable_fn<has_front<F>> use_front(F*, std::string*)
{ }
```

When calling, simply call both variants, and the compiler will select the appropriate action based on the SFINAE test.

```
template<typename T>
void push_pop(string *str, T *container){
  use_top(container, str);
  use_front(container, str);
  container->pop();
}
```

It looks like we're calling both `top()` and `front()`, but depending on whether the container supports `top()` or `front()` one or the other function call will be compiled out. If the type `T` supports both `front()` and `top()`, it's a little problematic, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you to fix...

(NOTE: you'll need `enable_fn` which looks something like:

```
template <typename T>
using type_of = typename T::type;
template <typename C, typename R = void>
using enable_fn = type_of<std::enable_if<C::value, R>>;
```

I'll leave `disable_fn` as an exercise for you...

Comment: A bit unconventional, but TMP-generating macros are my cup of tea :) — I'd export some of that stuff to a `detail` namespace though, and why the `std::string` pointer parameter ?

Comment: The OP was using them, so left it as it was - frankly should be references in this case as the function does no check for `nullptr`!

Comment: It's far more complicated than I expected... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler has to compile both branches of the check, and it cannot compile `container.top()` for a queue nor `container.front()` for a stack.

You have to implement separate function templates for `std::queue` and `std::stack`:

```
template<typename V, typename C>
void push_pop(std::string &str, std::stack<V, C> &container) {
  str.push_back(container.top());
  container.pop();
}

template<typename V, typename C>
void push_pop(std::string &str, std::queue<V, C> &container) {
  str.push_back(container.front());
  container.pop();
}
```

It is possible (and I would recommend it) to do this for only the relevant parts:

```
template<typename V, typename C>
V const &first_element(std::stack<V, C> const &container) {
  return container.top();
}

template<typename V, typename C>
V const &first_element(std::queue<V, C> const &container) {
  return container.front();
}

template<typename T>
void push_pop(std::string &str, T &container) {
  str.push_back(first_element(container));
  container.pop();
}
```

Comment: You could generalize it some more by having `front()` as the default and overloading the function for `top()`.

Comment: It seems like another kind of overloading...
I may assume that due to language limitation, there is no way I could achieve the goal in one function body(as I did in question), right?

Comment: I don't think so, no. It's not too bad, though -- the stuff you have to put in different functions/function templates is only the part that would have been different anyway, so it's not like you have to hold a large amount of code in triplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem of your code is that you are trying to make run-time check which results in requirement to container class provide both top() and front().
One approach to solve this is, as @Wintermute suggests, to use template specialization.
If you want more fancy and generic way, you can use SFINAE approach, which in combination with C++11 gives clean and nice looking code. Assuming we have only two possible kinds of containers - with either front() or top() method provided (adding new kinds of functions is pretty easy):

```
template<typename container>
auto get_from_container(container* c, int) -> decltype(std::declval<container>().front(), typename container::value_type()) {
    return c->front();
}

template<typename container>                       
typename container::value_type get_from_container(container* c, long) {
    return c->top();
}

template<typename T>
void push_pop(string *str, T *containers){
    str->push_back(get_from_container(containers, 0)); containers->pop();
}
```

Notice second type argument in get_from_container - it is required to shadow "default" implementation with top() method (as described [here](http://ib-krajewski.blogspot.de/2013/10/some-basic-decltype-sfinae.html%20%22Some%20basic%20decltype-SFINAE))